# RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag tr found, expected closing tag td

Tags: java, html, xml, exception, runtimeexception

As you can see, my problem seems to be simple, just an inattention and forgetting to close a  tag, right?

error detail:

```
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag tr found, expected closing tag td.
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:135)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:396)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:71)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:236)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:214)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:175)
    at com.lecom.workflow.robo.satelite.inmetro.balcao.RbINMETROGeraProcedimentoSeiBalcao.createPdfFromHtmlString(RbINMETROGeraProcedimentoSeiBalcao.java:1626)
    at com.lecom.workflow.robo.satelite.inmetro.balcao.RbINMETROGeraProcedimentoSeiBalcao.executar(RbINMETROGeraProcedimentoSeiBalcao.java:257)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at br.com.lecom.workflow.servicos.business.ServicoBuilderRobo.executar(ServicoBuilderRobo.java:80)
    at com.lecom.workflow.robo.ExecutaRobo.run(ExecutaRobo.java:32)
    at com.lecom.workflow.robo.CustomRobotExecute.execute(CustomRobotExecute.java:19)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

And this is the Html code expecting a closing td tag:

```
<body> 
 <div id='container' style='width: 100%;'> 
       <h2> XXXXXXXXXXX </h2> 
       <p>Nº do Protocolo da Solicitação: XXXXXX </p> 
       <hr /> 
       <hr /> 
       <h2>Dados do Solicitante</h2> 
       <table> 
           <col width='33%' /> 
           <col width='34%' /> 
           <col width='33%' /> 
           <tr> 
               <td>CNPJ: XXXXXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td>Nome da Empresa/Instituição: XXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='2'>CPF: XXXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='3'>Nome: XXXXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='3'>E-mail: XXXXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td>Telefone: XXXXXXXX </td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='3'>UF: XX </td> 
           </tr> 
       </table> 
       <hr /> 
       <h2>Documentos anexos</h2> 
       <table id='tblAnexos'> 
           <thead> 
               <tr> 
                   <th>Nome</th> 
                   <th>Arquivo</th> 
               </tr> 
           </thead> 
           <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
           </tbody> 
       </table>  
       <br /> <br /> 
       <table> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='3'>Detalhameto da solicitação:</td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td colspan='3'>XXXXXXXXXXX<br /><br />XXXX<br />XXXXX</td> 
           </tr> 
       </table> 
       <h2>Documentos do Analista</h2> 
       <table id='tblAnexosAna'> 
           <thead> 
               <tr> 
                   <th>Nome</th> 
                   <th>Arquivo</th> 
               </tr> 
           </thead> 
           <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
                   <td>XXXXXXX</td> 
               </tr> 
           </tbody> 
       </table> 
       <h2>Outras Informações</h2> 
       <table> 
           <tr> 
               <td>Analista Responsável: XXXXXXX</td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td>Data do envio da solicitação: XXXXXXX</td> 
           </tr> 
       </table> 
   </div> 
 </body>
```

I spent hours and hours trying to identify the problem but without success.

OBS 1: I've only shared what's inside the  tag because I think it's the only relevant one.

OBS 2: Im using XMLParser:

```
    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes()));
```

the variable *htmlString* is the html from above

Comment: Please [do not post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1529709), post it directly as text in a code block.

Comment: Are you by any chance loading some other file? I tried parsing your HTML with itext's `XMLParser` and did not get an error...

Comment: I wonder if there might be an encoding problem around the text `<td colspan='3'>Detalhameto da solicitação:</td> ` such that the end tag has not been recognized because of a miscoding issue? Just an idea to be eliminated.

Comment: @MichaelKay No, that isn't the problem :'(